# React Routing causes inputs to lose focus

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have an app with a component that has inputs in it.  When the user changes the inputs, I want to update the query string in the URL to reflect the new state.  I achieve this by detecting a difference between the current `location.search` values and the query string that my state *would* generate.  If there's a difference, I return a `<Redirect>` component with the query args reflecting the new state.

The problem is that after every such redirect, the component re-renders and my inputs are replaced by new inputs, meaning that the input I just changed no longer exists, so it doesn't have focus.  If it's a text input, then it loses focus after every keystroke.

How I dealt with it was to remember the ID of the element that had focus when the state changed and then set focus to the new element based on `document.getElementById` once the component is done re-rendering.

I've reduced the issue down to a minimal app that is at https://codesandbox.io/s/github/TrevorMills/react-routing-conundrum.  The problem manifests on both functional components and `React.Component` classes.

My mechanism seems hacky to me.  My question to the React experts out there is, have I missed something? Is there a better way to get the state into the location query parms than `<Redirect>`?  I tried adding `key` to my inputs but it didn't make a difference.  If my mechanism seems legit, is there a way to apply it to the app on whole in a higher order component?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've edited your functional component version of the code, however the changes I made should be applicable to both.

The main thing I did is I removed the state duplication. Instead of duplicating the state from the route to the component, I just made the component use the query params directly as state. And then I made the updateState function update the query params using `props.history.replace` which is how React Router allows imperative navigation.

Hope this helps!

https://codesandbox.io/s/great-williamson-0pxyb

Comment: Thanks very much for this.  I like your tweak of just taking the state from the query parms.  Seems so obvious in retrospect.  And it seems like using `history.replace` is the way to go instead of using `<Redirect>`.

Comment: I changed my mind to make this the accepted answer because the insight about removing state duplication was the most profound lesson learned.  I did end up implementing my component to take the state from the query params directly and that felt like a big weight off.

Answer (score 4):

Since you were using redirect, on every change of input value, the component rendering toggles between the returned value and the redirect causing all components to remount instead of re-render. This causes the input field to lose focus.

Avoid using `<Redirect />` and use `history.replace` after updating the state.

Instead of doing `history.replace` in `onChangeText`  function, you can write a `useEffect`, like this.

```js
useEffect(() => {
    props.history.replace(props.location.pathname + "?" + qs.stringify(state));
  }, [state]);
```

Updated working example is here:

https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-swirles-kcqwo?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Accepting this answer because of the explanation of the toggling between returned values.  The ideas in both answers here are similar and very helpful.